# Direction of the gradient of a monotone function on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $f:\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing along a certain circle (I am interested in great circles in particular) that lies on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. My intuition is that the surface gradient $\nabla_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f$ is tangent to that circle. Correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of a function (when you have a metric defined, like here) is a vector tangent to the surface of $S^{n-1}$. But is not necessarily tangent to any circle along which the function increase. In fact, it will be tangent only to **the curve of maximal increase**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am not sure what the curve of maximal increase is. So let me ask: what about the specific example of $f$ being the geodesic distance from a fixed point on the sphere. Would the surface gradient be tangent to the great circle whose length gives the geodesic distance ?

Comment: When you have a function defined on a surface and you fix a point $x_0$, you can leave it in many directions. Depending of which one you take, your specific function will have a different slope. The gradient is a vector that tells you what is the direction in which the slope is maximum.

Comment: Clear. Thanks again.

Comment: In the specific context that you are saying above, the answer is YES. You obtain the maximal increase when you continue the great circle joining your fixed point with the selected point.